# How to get rows distinct by one field using another field to choose the one if there are many in an Sqlite table?

Tags: sqlite

Lets consider a following SQlite example table storing multiple versions of same records:

```
CREATE TABLE MyRecords(
id LONG NOT NULL,
version LONG NOT NULL,
text TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (id ASC, version ASC)
);
```

How to get only one row for every distinct `id` value using the `version` column to choose the one (having the highest `version` value if there are more than one saved in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyRecords r1
WHERE version = (SELECT MAX(version) FROM MyRecords r2 WHERE r1.id = r2.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab max versions per id and then join back to get the text values

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM (
    SELECT id, MAX(version) version
      FROM MyRecords
     GROUP BY id
) q JOIN MyRecords r
    ON q.id = r.id
   AND q.version = r.version
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/39dcf/1)

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite 3.7.11 or later, you can simply [use max() to select which row in a group to return](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bareagg):

```
SELECT id,
       MAX(version) AS version,
       text
FROM MyRecords
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: Won't this just replace the actual `version` field value with the maximum version value known in records returned rather than actually returning all the the real records discarding those having same `id` but lower`version`?

Comment: No; [GROUP BY](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset) returns one row per `id`, and as explained in the link, the `text` values come from the correct rows.